# MultipleActiveResultSets=True or multiple connections?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ado.net

I have some C# in which I create a reader on a connection (`ExecuteReader`), then for every row in that reader, perform another command (with `ExecuteNonQuery`).  In this case is it better that I use `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` on my connection or use multiple connections?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) was added specifically for this type of operation so that you don't have to have two connections open at the same time to be able to read from a SqlDataReader AND execute additional batches.

MARS is compatible with SQL Server 2005 and above. To quote from MSDN docs:

> Before the introduction of Multiple
>   Active Result Sets (MARS), developers
>   had to use either multiple connections
>   or server-side cursors to solve
>   certain scenarios.

For more info see:

> [MSDN Library - MARS Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cfa084cz.aspx)

Worked example reading and updating data:

> [MSDN Library - Manipulating Data (MARS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/yf1a7f4f.aspx) scroll down to 'Reading and Updating Data with MARS'

Comment: By setting the Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) to true, will improve the overall performance of retrieving data from the database.

Answer (score 25):

This is as far as I know the reason MARS was added, so yeah I think you should use it.

Answer (score -1):

Best way to test this is to fire SQLServer Profiler, and see what really happens on the server side.

My guess is that it will not be better since you are using ExecuteNonQuery(). So, in fact, you don't work with multiple results.

Comment: That's what I thought when I wrote the code, but if I don't have MultipleActiveResultSets=True then I still get an "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first." exception on ExecuteNonQuery.