# C# MySQL second DataReader in DataReader while loop

Tags: c#, mysql, database, connection, datareader

As you might have guessed from the title am I trying to do this:

```
    #region check new nations
    private void checknewnations()
    {
        addtolog("server","Checking for new nations");
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM " + variables.tbl_nations + " WHERE nations_new=0";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            addtolog("mysql",reader["nations_name"].ToString());

            int nation_ID = int.Parse(reader["nations_ID"].ToString());
            string nation_name = reader["nations_name"].ToString();
            string user_ID = reader["nations_user"].ToString();


            addnation(nation_ID, nation_name, user_ID);
        }
        addtolog("server","Finished checking for new nations.");
        //connection.Close();
        reader.Dispose();
    }
    #endregion
```

which calls this in the while loop:

```
    #region addnation
    private void addnation(int nationIDnot, string nationName, string userID)
    {
        string nationID = makesixdigits(nationIDnot);
        string userName = "";

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM " + variables.tbl_users + " WHERE users_ID=" + userID;
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        while (reader.Read())
        {
            userName = reader["users_name"].ToString();
        }
        reader.Dispose();
        addtolog("add", "[" + nationID.ToString() + "] " + nationName + " [" + userID + "] " + userName);
    }
    #endregion
```

This gives me an error in the second block of code (the one that is called upon in the while loop) saying that there already is a datareader associated with the connection. How am I to get this to work, because I am sure there is a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2008 connection strings you can have multiple active results sets via `MultipleActiveResultSets=true;` I've not used mySQL so I'm not sure, but maybe if you are using an ADO provider.

Otherwise, just make another connection -- don't re-use the same one.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. It is such an obvious and easy solution :)

Comment: Does MARS work with MySQL? I thought it was still specific to SQLServer 2005 and later. (I mostly just use multiple connections anyway unless I really need to do stuff from interleaving calls in the same transaction).

Comment: @JonHanna - I didn't think it did, but a MS user could read this question so I covered the base.

Comment: Good point. Oh hai MS user! Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx before using MARS.

Comment: I am not using that mars thingy, just the multiple connections :) 3 extra lines of code :)

Answer (score 5):

DataReader holds on to connection until it iterates through all its records. Try this

```
using(reader)
{
   System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
   dt.Load(reader);

   foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
   {
        addtolog("mysql",row["nations_name"].ToString());

        int nation_ID = int.Parse(row["nations_ID"].ToString());
        string nation_name = row["nations_name"].ToString();
        string user_ID = row["nations_user"].ToString();


        addnation(nation_ID, nation_name, user_ID);
   }
}
```

This way the two reader are not sharing the same connection

Comment: Would that make a local version of the table?

Comment: All records are loaded into `dt` at once and the reader is free

Comment: This approach of loading the DataReader result set into a DataTable looks handy for some small result set scenarios I run into. For example, a top-level "Client/Person" row, which then has 0..n child rows to loop through, where "n" typically is a "few" i.e., not "thousands". If each of those child rows potentially relates to 0..n additional data rows in multiple other tables, this approach would be useful for looping through those first-level child rows without tying up a connection.

Answer (score 1):

Open another connection in the loop, and use it to obtain the second reader.
Since the loop is tight, you might prefer to open both connections in the first method, pass the second through to the called method, and then close them both at the end of the first ("outer") method. It should be a short enough time between calls that the normal rule about closing connections as soon as possible won't matter.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) I am now using 2 connections, though I am opening them at the start of the program and close them at the end of the program, because the first while loop is also part of a loop/timer_tick so the connections get almost constantly used.

Comment: @user1599326 if it's a single-threaded console app that fits into the lose spec of "do db stuff, then end" (!) then that's fine; there isn't anything else sharing the connection pool anyway.

Comment: Just remember that it falls under the category of bending rules because it's just a small app that does stuff and doesn't end; "hey what's the scalability impact of the way we..." "who cares, the program ended before you got to the end of that question!" :)

Comment: Well, the program is actually designed to be a constant running server program (only with a connection with the MySql database, not directly with the clients)

Comment: In that case you *really* want to create and open the connections at the start of the method, and close them at the end (ideally with `using`  to make sure this happens in the face of an exception). Concurrent threads dealing with concurrent client connections (as in the server app's clients) will have separate connections (otherwise you get the same exception as above in one of the clients and don't know why) and pooling keeps connection overheades and total DB connection count low as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/3845924/400547