# MultipleActiveResultSet is disabled but it works fine

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I have got the idea of `MultipleActiveResultSets`; problem is that even if i dont make it `true` in my Connection String it still do work. If it works properly without making `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` why we still do need it?

Following is my code:

Controls: 2 DataGridView and One Button "button1"

Objects: 2 SqlCommand, 2 SqlDataReader, 2 DataTable, 1 SqlConnection

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=COMP18-PC;Initial Catalog=Company;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");

        SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand("select * from emp", conn);
        SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand("select * from dept", conn);

        SqlDataReader dr1;
        SqlDataReader dr2;

        conn.Open();

        dr1 = com1.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        dt1.Load(dr1);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt1;

        dr2 = com2.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        dt2.Load(dr2);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dt2;

        conn.Close();            
    }
```

This code works perfectly fine even though i haven't used `MultipleActiveResultSet` in the connection string.
I have even taken the same `SqlDataReader` for both the queries and even same `SqlCommand` but it works fine. **So where we have to use MultipleActiveResultSets?**

My problem is not about "when to use it?" its about I am not using it when I have to but it doesnt show me any error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MultipleActiveResultSets=True or multiple connections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510899/multipleactiveresultsets-true-or-multiple-connections)

Comment: What makes you think the code you've posted is _actually using_ the MARS functionality?  I would expect that calling `DataTable.Load` on a `SqlDataReader` to read it right to the end, and it therefore no longer be "active".

Comment: I am performing a read on the same connection without making MultipleActiveResultSets so it should come up with an error, that is not happening