# EF Core large queries throwing transport-level error

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am porting over code from a .NET Framework project to .NET 8 and I'm seeing the following error:

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the
> server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection
> is not usable)

While I've read through several of the other posts related to this exception I'm still not sure what the real problem is.  I have a pretty simple query:

```
await _dbContext
    .Set<Setting>()
    .Where(setting => setting.Type == type)
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

If I limit the query to fewer than 80 records, I do not get this error but any more than that and I start to get it, also if I remove "MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" from my connection string the error goes away.

I'm not sure I should get rid of that setting and I don't think the amount of data is large enough to warrant this exception.

Is there a reason that MultipleActiveResultSets would throw this error when using Entity Framework Core when it worked fine before?

Comment: MARS allows the execution of multiple batches on a single connection. If you never do that, you can disable it.

Comment: Can you explain what that means in practice?  Also, that doesn't explain why I'm getting the error, MARS didn't cause any issues until switching to EF Core.

Comment: Somewhere else in your code you may retrieve another data or make another connection. İt seems like try to use async. İ mean you do some ef operations in parallel. Mars is not thread-safe. it is not about only how big your received results in single query.

Comment: Try to use each single query with by new seperated dbcontext instance . You might not face the same error regardles of your connection string include Mars or not.

Comment: I’m running in debug, I can add a breakpoint and step over the line that runs that query and if I pull back all rows with MARS enabled it throws the exception.  If I limit the rows it works fine.  Nothing else hits the database.  I’ve tried with and without async

Comment: Do not activate MARS if you don't know why it is needed. Actually it is special protocol for communication with SQL Server and as I know has limitations [Disadvantages of MARS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374444/disadvantages-of-mars-multiple-active-result-sets)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv There are obvious [Advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59607616/when-should-i-use-multipleactiveresultsets-true-when-working-with-asp-net-core-3/67037234#67037234) though. Especially for streaming entities with related collections with Split Queries.